# Does the Belkin N150 support ADSL2+?

Tags: adsl-router

Does the [Belkin N150](http://www.belkin.com/IWCatProductPage.process?Product_Id=492429) 
Support ADSL2+?

It has a model number of F6D4630-4 v2

The website or manual doesn't seem to mention it. Or am I just looking in the wrong place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model you are talking about doesn't support ADSL2. This a wireless routeur so you'd need a modem

The one you'd need would be this one:

http://www.belkin.com/in/IWCatProductPage.process?Product_Id=492851

This one is, by the look, almost the same as you have but has the ADSL2 feature since it's a modem/router.

Comment: OK, I seem to have made a mistake with the link I provided. I have the modem in front of me and I definately know it is an ADSL modem, not just a router. The modem I have must be the one in your link. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, please upvote then ;)